# Sphinx runs doctests multiple times due to 'from X import Y'

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest, coverage.py

I have a project set up to run `doctests` from Sphinx, via `automodule`.

However, it appears that not only do the module's tests get run, so does anything with the syntax of:

```
from some.module.path import foobar
```

This results in `foobar`'s doctests being run as well, which is not desired.

Is there a way to disable this, and make sure that only doctests *declared* in a given file are run?

Doctests are run via:

```
coverage3 run -m sphinx -b doctest docs/source docs/build/doctest
```